# Configuring OpenSessionInViewFilter with Spring 3 and Servlet 3

Tags: hibernate, spring, servlet-3.0, open-session-in-view

i want to configure `OpenSessionInViewFilter` to able to use hibernate lazy initialization in view, so i added the filter definition in web.xml, but it doesn't work i still get the same lazy initialization exception, here's what i did:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
      version="3.0"> 

  <display-name>MyApp</display-name>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml
        classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationSecurity.xml
        </param-value>

  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>


  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>


  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>


    <filter>
      <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
            <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
            <param-value>ERROR</param-value>
      </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
      <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
      <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
      <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
         <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>         
      </init-param>      
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping> 



  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.CompatResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/xmlhttp/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**applicationContext:**

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="${project.groupId}.domain" />


        <!-- control the behavior of Hibernate at runtime,All are optional and have reasonable default values -->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
            <!-- hibernate.dialect: allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular relational database -->
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
                hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
                hibernate.show_sql=true
                hibernate.format_sql=true
            </value>
        </property>

    </bean>
```

please advise why i am **still getting the lazy initialization exception**, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems that the order in which the filter chain is constructed depends on the order that the filter-mapping elements appear.

In other words, try putting filter-mapping of OpenSessionInViewFilter before any other filter-mapping.

Good luck with that

Comment: moved it to be before the spring security and it works just fine, thanks.

Comment: I struggled with this problem a whole day. The issue was just the order of the filters. Very, very big thank you!

Comment: Question: if I have a `CharsetEncodingFilter` for resolving/representing/processing special characters in request/url, what may comes first? I tried to put `CharsetEncodingFilter` first and I get lazyinitialization exception, but if I don't put it first, special characters are not processed correctly.